# Inproper values are put into a list in C#

Tags: c#, list

This is my piece of code:

```
List<Firma> dane = new List<Firma>();
Firma firma = new Firma();
while (reader.Read())
{
    firma.Nazwa = (string)reader["Nazwa"];
    firma.Skrot = (string)reader["IDfirmy"];
    firma.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
    dane.Add(firma);
}
```

I have two records with different values in my database, but after this code has executed I have two exactly the same elements in `dane` list. I've put a breakpoint on `dane.Add(firma);` and there is something I do not understand. During first iteration of `while` I have correct value in `firma` and nothing in `dane` (so everything is pretty normal), but during second iteration I have new values in `firma` (still OK), but the first element in `dane` list (added in previous iteration) has values of second iteration's `firma`.

Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying same reference of `Firma` class which is added in list.

Create ***new instance in while loop*** instead:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Firma firma = new Firma();
    firma.Nazwa = (string)reader["Nazwa"];
    firma.Skrot = (string)reader["IDfirmy"];
    firma.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
    dane.Add(firma);
}
```

OR

Have declaration outside but ***with every iteration, create a new object*** so that it doesn't affect already added object reference in list.

```
Firma firma = null;
while (reader.Read())
{
    firma = new Firma();
    firma.Nazwa = (string)reader["Nazwa"];
    firma.Skrot = (string)reader["IDfirmy"];
    firma.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
    dane.Add(firma);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that putting `Firma firma = new Firma();` in a loop will cause a namespace problem. Second example look much more natural for me. ;)

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are operating on the same instance in each iteration. Try this:

```
List<Firma> dane = new List<Firma>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Firma firma = new Firma();
    firma.Nazwa = (string)reader["Nazwa"];
    firma.Skrot = (string)reader["IDfirmy"];
    firma.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
    dane.Add(firma);
}
```

In your version, you put the same `Firma` object into the list twice (two references pointing to the same object), and overwrite its properties in the second iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is that you are not creating instance of Firma class in each iteration

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Firma firma = new Firma();
    firma.Nazwa = (string)reader["Nazwa"];
    firma.Skrot = (string)reader["IDfirmy"];
    firma.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
    dane.Add(firma);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    dane.Add(new Firma {
        Nazwa = (string)reader["Nazwa"],
        Skrot = (string)reader["IDfirmy"],
        ID = (int)reader["ID"]
    });
}
```

Then you don't have to worry about where to put the reference of `Firma`.